# Remove word "real" from the string after its first occurrence using HashMap

Tags: java

It is not looping through the if loop in the code. 
The desired o/p is:

```
This is real project with  problems  problems are tough to solve
```

My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "This is real project with real problems real problems are tough to solve";
    String key = "real";
    int count = 0;
    Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s);
    Integer v = null;
    String next;
    while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
        next = st.nextToken();
        // To assign unique key to the value in the string
        if (v == null)
            v = 1;
        else
            v++;
        map.put(v, next);
    }
    System.out.println("before: " + map);
    System.out.println(count);
    //To delete the word "real" from the string
    for (int i = 0; i <= map.size(); i++) {
        //This is not working
        if (map.containsValue("real") && count >= 1) {
            //To delete value in the hashMap with ""
            next = "";
        }
        count++;
    }

    System.out.println("After deleting: " + map );
}
```

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: I am getting the same o/p before performing the for loop.
before: {1=This, 2=is, 3=real, 4=project, 5=with, 6=real, 7=problems, 8=real, 9=problems, 10=are, 11=tough, 12=to, 13=solve}

Comment: What exactly do you think `next = "";` is going to accomplish?

Comment: I think it will remove the word "real" in the map after its first occurrence.!!

Comment: Evidently. But why would it do that?

Comment: Here my count is 3 and I am writing  if (map.containsValue("real") && count >= 1).. So, if map contains the word "real" in its value I thought it would delete it. Correct me if I am wrong.
Please let me know if u know how to resolve it.

Comment: "I thought it would delete it" but, what makes you think that setting variable `name` to `""` should affect map (its structure or content) in any way. [Java is not pass-by-reference but pass-by-value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what you're trying to do in your loop. But if I've understood your requirements, this should do it:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= map.size(); i++) {
    if ("real".equals(map.get(i)) && count++ >= 1) {
        map.remove(i);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
After deleting: {1=This, 2=is, 3=real, 4=project, 5=with, 7=problems, 9=problems, 10=are, 11=tough, 12=to, 13=solve}
```

Comment: but I want the first real to be there. This code deletes all the "real" 's in the string

Comment: @sai did you test it?

Comment: yeah. I tested it .. It worked but this removes the first occurred "real" in the map also but I want the first occurred "real" and the next occurrences must be removed.

Comment: @sai, no it doesn't. Look at the output I posted.

Comment: yeah. I don't know y i am not getting the correct o/p.

Comment: Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
  StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s);
  Integer v = null;
  String next;
  while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
   next = st.nextToken();
   if (v == null)
    v = 1;
   else
    v++;
   map.put(v, next);
  }
  System.out.println("before: " + map);
  
  for (int i = 1; i <= map.size(); i++) {
      if ("real".equals(map.get(i)) && count++ >= 1) {
          map.remove(i);
      }
  }
  
  System.out.println("After deleting: " + map );

Comment: @sai You missed `String s = "This is real project with real problems real problems are tough to solve"; int count = 0;`. After adding I get the same output: `After deleting: {1=This, 2=is, 3=real, 4=project, 5=with, 7=problems, 9=problems, 10=are, 11=tough, 12=to, 13=solve}`

Comment: Yeah. I got it..Thanku so much but Can you help me to print this o/p as a string?

Comment: If you have Java 8, you can do this `System.out.println(String.join(" ", map.values()));`. But I would recommend using `LinkedHashMap`, because iteration order is not guaranteed for `HashMap`.

Comment: String repeated[] = null;
  
  for(String s1:map.keySet()){
   if(map.get(s1).equals(biggest))
    repeated[0]=s1;
  if(map.get(s1).equals(secondBiggest))
   repeated[1]=s1;
  } 
  return repeated;

I would like to return two strings as a string array. how to return array of strings? i'm getting nullpointer exception. so how to overcome and how can i return 

my map has{real=6,to=2,world=1,hello=0}
so i want to return real and to which are top two repeating elements. so how can in return them through string array

Answer (score 2):

Let's keep it simple:

```
String s = "This is real project with real problems real problems are tough to solve";
String key = "real";
// Get the index of the first occurrence
int index = s.indexOf(key);
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(s.length());
// Adds to the first part of the string
buffer.append(s.substring(0, index + key.length()));
// Adds to the second part of the string from which we removed the next occurences
buffer.append(s.substring(index + key.length()).replace(key, ""));
System.out.println(buffer);
```

**Output:**

```
This is real project with  problems  problems are tough to solve
```